# React Quill-js ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: reactjs, vite, quill

i'm trying to implement react quill js as a rich text editor in my newsletter component, it works fine in developmenet, but it crashed the app in th e production build, with this error

`ReferenceError: require is not defined`

i'm using vite
here is my **Newsletter.jsx**

```
import { useQuill } from "react-quilljs";
import "quill/dist/quill.snow.css";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import axios from "axios"
import { useState } from "react";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import Toast from "./../../components/Toast"
import notify from "./../../utils/notify"


const Newsletter = () => {

   const formik = useFormik({
     initialValues: {
       subject: ""
     },
     validationSchema: Yup.object({
       subject: Yup.string()
         .max(32, "C'est trop long !")
         .min(3, "C'est trop court !")
         .required("Ce champ est obligatoire !")
     }),
     onSubmit: (values) => {
       if (quill.getText().length >= 60){
        setButtonDisabled(true)
        toast.loading("sending",{autoClose:false})
        axios
          .post("/newsletter", {
            subject: values.subject,
            msg: quillRef.current.firstChild.innerHTML,
          })
          .then(() => {
            toast.dismiss();
            setButtonDisabled(false);

            notify("done", "success");
          })
          .catch(() => {
            toast.dismiss();
            setButtonDisabled(false);
            notify("failed", "error");
          });
       }else{
        notify("ecrire au moins une ligne","error")
       }
     },
   });
      
 
  const { quill , quillRef } = useQuill();
  const [buttonDisabled, setButtonDisabled] = useState(false);
  



  return (
    <main className="overflow-y-scroll h-[90vh] w-full">
      <h1 className="m-auto font-bold text-[26px] text-center my-16 selection:text-[#f00049cc]">
        Newsletters - Paneau De Control
      </h1>

      <Toast />
      <section className="w-[500px] p-5 flex flex-col gap-6 ">
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-3">
          <p className="text-[#71717A]">
            envoyez des masse messages aux votre patients usual{" "}
          </p>
        </div>

        <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
          <div className=" my-4 flex flex-col gap-4">
            <label htmlFor="subject">Sujet:</label>

            <input
              type="text"
              name="subject"
              id="subject"
              autoFocus
              placeholder="Announce"
              className="bg-[rgba(0,0,0,0.03)] p-4 rounded-lg w-full"
              {...formik.getFieldProps("subject")}
            />
            {formik.touched.subject && formik.errors.subject ? (
              <small className="text-red-500 font-semibold ">
                {formik.errors.subject}
              </small>
            ) : null}
          </div>
          <div className="h-96 flex  flex-col gap-4">
            <div ref={quillRef} />

            <button
              type="submit"
              className={`w-1/4 p-3   rounded-md  self-end cursor-pointer ${
                buttonDisabled ? "bg-[#00284e7e]" : "bg-[#00284E]"
              } text-white`}
              disabled={buttonDisabled}
            >
              Envoyer
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </section>
    </main>
  );
}

export default Newsletter`
```

i checked github issues and fixed with no results, seems that the common reason for this error is using the **require** function in the client side code, which i'm not using it explicitly in my code

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).